# Text file import not working in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face, easeljs

I need to use EaselJS for a project and import some fonts.

I wanted to use Google Fonts instead, but you need WiFi, and my project shouldn't need WiFi.

I tried to import the font in CSS like so-

```
    @font-face {

        font-family: Sample;
        src: url(font/Organo.ttf);

    }
```

And then I made some text using EaselJS-

```
    var txt = new createjs.Text();
    txt.x = txt.y = 500;
    txt.font = "96px Sample";
    txt.color = "#FF7700";
    txt.text = "Hello World!";

    stage.addChild(txt);
    stage.update();
```

There are no errors showing up in the console, but the font looks like the default Times New Roman. However, it is supposed to look like this-
[image]

I have tried it with regular HTML elements, and it seems to work out well while importing it there.

Is there any other way I can import fonts in EaselJS? [This](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Fonts/) is the only other EaselJS font tutorial I found. Why is this font not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it should work fine.

Make sure that you are updating the stage *after* the font is loaded. In your sample code you update the stage one time after creating the text.

Here is a quick sample loading a font from another domain. Notice that it flickers with the default font first, before showing the actual font.

http://jsfiddle.net/bt0hk5wq/

I added a tick listener to the stage, so it will constantly update.

```
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
```

There is some work done on Font loading in PreloadJS, however it is still in an in-progress branch:

- [FontLoader branch](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/tree/FontLoader)
- [FontLoader source](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/blob/FontLoader/src/preloadjs/loaders/FontLoader.js)
- [Font loading example using a font file](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/blob/FontLoader/spikes/FontLoading/testSrc.html)

The FontLoader support is still in beta, but hopefully will be integrated into the official source soon (March, 2016?)

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Lanny- That worked out really well, thanks a lot. However, the delay is very long for mobile devices, and I do not want that to happen. I set a `setTimeout` function and then pasted the code above, but the same thing had happened. Is there any way to do it without this delay?

Comment: The delay is the font loading and initializing. Once it is ready, it will draw

Answer (score 0):

Is the font stored locally?  If so try

```
@font-face {

        font-family: Sample;
        src: local("Organo");

    }
```

Else, try some quotes

```
@font-face {

    font-family: Sample;
    src: url("font/Organo.ttf");

}
```